# Is there a way to change thread's locale using MFC with C++

Tags: c++, mfc, internationalization

I'm working on internationalization and I was wondering if there is a way to change a thread's locale using MFC with C++. The reason is that some countries can have a short date format of dd-MMM-yyyy and I want to be able to detect that in our application and then modify the thread's locale to something like dd/MM/yyyy instead of using dd-MMM-yyyy.

Let me explain more of what I'm trying to do. I know that I can format individual dates. My goal is to modify locale info for short date format for all  threads in my MFC application. I've already done this in a ASP.NET web app with C# by using CurrentThread and setting it's CurrentCulture to a new CultureInfo object that I've cloned and modified so that the short date format is different. I'm just wondering if something similar can be done but instead using MFC and C++.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about something substantially different from [`SetThreadLocale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051.aspx)?

Comment: **[Maybe this documentation explains it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235302.aspx)**

Comment: You don't have to change a thread's locale to format a string. Just supply your locale of choice using [`_wprintf_l`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx) for example.

Comment: I'm not trying to format a single string. I'm trying to modify the locale info in each thread in my MFC application since our application does not support short date format that contain 'MMM' or 'MMMM'.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't. Don't touch the thread locale, that's just asking for problems.

Instead, call [`COleDateTime::Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bab3feb1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or perhaps [`GetDateFormatEx(LOCALE_NAME_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_LONGDATE, myDate, 0, outStr, outStrLen, 0)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)